# define Data in Python3 in a C-struct-like way

Tags: python, c, indexing, struct

In C structures are very handy in definitions e.g.
status data of a controller could look like this:

```
typedef struct {
  float p, i, d;
  float output;
} controller_t;
```

Now let a hardware module contain 4 controllers each using above data:

```
typedef struct {
  int moduleActive;
  byte moduleAddress;
  controller_t con[4];
} status_t;

status_t st;
```

In functions these data can easily referenced like

```
st.moduleActive = 1;
st.con[2].p = 2.34;
```

A function performing a control-loop could use the data by simply passing an index.

Question: How would a comparable and easy to use data structure look like in Python3 ?

Comment: well, downvoting my question feels somewhat trolly. I really have a migration problem between the two languages: fast simulation and test of a task in Python, then port the solution to C for a smaller microcontroller which cannot use Python. Testing and Changing and watching diagrams of a more complicated regualtion system is five times faster than in C. I really ask you to understand this intention. Maybe I should have put this information eralier in my question, but tried to keep it short.

Comment: Not the person who downvoted, but rules/guidelines on questions that ask how to translate from 1 language to another [can be a bit blurry](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/296119/is-how-do-i-convert-code-from-this-language-to-this-language-too-broad). What you could have posted is your attempt at creating the classes in Python, and describe what went wrong with it. That shows some level of understanding and *specific* problem/s to solve, and hopefully won't make people think that they need to provide a full on tutorial on classes.

Comment: that's certainly right. My tries led me to some weird solutions; so I intended to avoid wrong or bad traces to be corrected. I believe the question above was emphasized and clear. Thanks to fellow-programmers who can undertand me and the problems well, in spite of my bad habits haunting this forum I got a fast and very helpful answer; I hope there is hope for my improvement.

Answer (score 1):

Since Python is an Object-Oriented Language, it uses Classes instead of structs. Along with parameters, Python classes can also support methods. If you do not know how to use Python classes, I strongly recommend using a Python tutorial online.

Comment: Thank you, I made the py-tutorial on the python homepage. I tried several methods, but was not satisfactory. Surely I am missing something, this is why I ask the community for better ideas. I frequently use python3 for program drafts to test the functionality. Later on it has to be converted to C for low-level Microcontrollers. So it would be comfortable to have something similar. Had  no luck with an array of a class holding the data ;c)

Comment: @peets - explaining what you tried and what was not satisfactory about it in your question would make for a much better question that is more likely to get you the answer you want.

Comment: @Craig: that's true. Was a bit shy to post non-functioning pieces of code  or mislead answers to a wrong direction (was trying a lot of partly not suitable code like dictionarys or lists)

Comment: @peets also note that in C++ struct and class are not that different, https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/structure-vs-class-in-cpp/

Comment: The only major difference between a struct and a class is that classes can also have class methods.

Answer (score 1):

If you create a class like this, it will work like a C struct:

```
class Status():
    moduleActive = 0
    moduleAddress = 0
    con = [0]*4
```

Here are some examples:

```
In [20]: st = Status

In [21]: st.con
Out[21]: [0, 0, 0, 0]

In [22]: st.con[2] = 2.34

In [23]: st.con
Out[23]: [0, 0, 2.34, 0]

In [24]: st.moduleActive = 1

In [25]: st.moduleActive
Out[25]: 1
```

If `controller_t` is also a struct, then create a class for that too. I just used an array here because you don't specify what is in `controller_t`.

This approach above only creates class variables, which will be the same for all instances of the class. If you want to have multiple instances, you will need to create a class with the `__init__()` method. Inside `__init__` you can define instance variables that are unique to the instance.

```
class Status2():
    def __init__(self):
        self.moduleActive = 0
        self.moduleAddress = 0
        self.con = [0]*4
```

Now, when you create an instance of the class, it will have its instance variables that aren't shared with other instances of that class.

```
In [32]: sta = Status2()     
                             
In [33]: sta.con             
Out[33]: [0, 0, 0, 0]        
                             
In [34]: stb = Status2()     

In [35]: stb.con
Out[35]: [0, 0, 0, 0]

In [36]: stb.con[2] = 2.34

In [37]: stb.con
Out[37]: [0, 0, 2.34, 0]

In [38]: sta.con
Out[38]: [0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Comment: Thanks Craig! helped me. The list solution you posted is fine. I tried a class for controller_t but made something wrong defining the 'class - in - a - class'.  This finally led me to the posted question. I forgot to initiate it as you did in input line [20]

Comment: ...  yes, the  last class definition is what I was looking for! Thanks again.